# MERN Stack: Saving Form Data to mLab - Formatting Issue

Tags: forms, express, mongoose, mern

I am getting the data from my form to my mLab but it is formatted in a way i don't like. it comes though like this

`{ '{"email":"ben@benjamin.com","message":"not what i want"}': '' }`

and even worse it saves as this

`"data": "{\"{\\\"email\\\":\\\"ben@benjamin.com\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"this is ridiculous\\\"}\":\"\"}"`

so it is setting my data as the key to nothing basically.  i resorted to changing my Schema to an Object just so i can save something.  ideally i want a key for each piece of data. and i want to be able to access it later.  i couldn't get body parser to work so i am using express-formidable as middleware.  there are alot of moving parts and if i change things around i crash the server and get error no matter what i do.  okay here is some of the code from both sides.

---

SERVER CODE:

```
var formSchema = new Schema({
   data: Object
})
app.use(formidable());

app.post('/contact', function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.fields)
   var item = JSON.stringify(req.fields)

   var form = new Form({data: item
}).save(function(err,data){
       if(err) throw err
       if(data) res.json(data)
   })
})
```

---

CLIENT SIDE CODE

```
submitData(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let email = this.state.value;
    let msg = this.state.value2;
    let data = {
        email: email,
        message: msg
    }
    fetch('/contact', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 },
 body: JSON.stringify(data)
 })  
 .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            console.log("Response:",responseData);
            this.setState({
                value: "",
                value2: "",
                status: "THANKS FOR CONTACTING ME I'LL BE IN TOUCH SOON"
            })
         }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
         })
}
```

---

this is driving me insane.  ideally i would like to do it right. or somehow access the object and get at the email and message keys and just change my Schema.  then i could assign the keys in my new Form(... section

Answer (score 0):

In a bizarre twist of events i solved it sort of.  this can't be the best way but it works.  i would still like to know where along the line i went wrong.  i saw a tutorial where the form data was easily saved...granted in wasn't from a react front end...anyway this is what i did

My Custom Solution

```
var formSchema = new Schema({
   email: String,
   message: String
})
app.use(urlencodedParser);
app.post('/contact', function(req,res,next){
    var item = Object.keys(req.body)
    var o = JSON.parse(item[0])
    var e = o.email
    var m = o.message
    console.log(e)
   //var item = JSON.stringify(req.fields)
   var form = new Form({email: e,message: m
}).save(function(err,data){
       if(err) throw err
       if(data) res.json(data)
   })
})
```

i switched back to body-parser from formidable but either way i was getting that weird object

---

i still don't know why my data object was `{'{'key':'value'}':''}` i thought my problem was on the server side...but maybe it is something with how i send the POST.  someone smarter and more experienced isnt hard to find :)